# xcode web view for all screen sizes

Tags: xcode

I have read so many papers regarding Xcode/iPhone screen sizes when developing. What I am working on is a very simple application that only uses a WebView. This will connect to a web page which has a single table with a width of 100%.

In xcode I have the following set:
On the WebView: Use Auto layout, Scales to fit ticked.

Am I missing a setting or some code to make the web page fit the screens for all iPhones.

Any pointers, tutorials or examples would be very helpful.

In my ViewControllor I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[self hasInternet];

[WebView loadRequest:
 [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/sys/app/index.php"]]];
WebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
WebView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

}

Regards,

Comment: Are you using constraints? You could select your webview and add constraints of 0 your superview on all sides (top, right, bottom, left), using this menu: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qU9Vl.png

Comment: @Meriw Hi, Thanks for your reply. I am not using constraints but I am currently looking at them and how best to use. I will let you know.

Comment: Just for clarification, the 'scales page to fit' parameter actually fits the scale of the web content to the UIWebView size. To actually make the UIWebView of the size of the iPhone screen you should be using constraints. I believe the easiest way to start is by using that menu I pointed out earlier. Good luck and don't forget to update your question so I or anyone else can answer it properly :)

Comment: @Meriw. Hi, many thanks for pointing me to constraints. I learned a lot. All sorted.